# Adding something to the beginning of a list with ':' operator in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, functional-programming, where-clause

I started studying Haskell few days ago, went through the basics and there's a few things left that I can't make sense of.

First of all, 
when I try to add something to the beginning of a list with the ':' operator in a GHCi console, it works only if I try to add single literals, but not lists. (`5:[1,2,3,4]`) would work but (`[1,2]:[3,4,5]`) would not. However there's this function:

```
replicate2 n x
| n <= 0    = []
| otherwise = x:replicate2 (n-1) x
```

As i understand this how it works recursively, let's call `replicate2 2 [1,2]`:
it will slip through the first guard and hence:

```
= [1,2]:replicate (2-1) [1,2]

= [1,2]:[1,2]:replicate (1-1) [1,2] 

 -- since n is now 0 it's an edge condition and first guard returns [], so recursion ends and we get:

= [1,2]:[1,2]:[]
```

and the function returns `[[1,2],[1,2]]`

My question: How does this work? Shouldn't Haskell be mad and spit out errors? It does when I try to do that in GHCi.

Comment: The `(:)` operator adds *one item* to the beginning of a list. That's why `1:[2,3,4]` is fine, but `[1,2]:[3,4]` isn't; you're trying to add a *list* to the front.

Comment: yes, exactly, my question was about the function i provided. It DOES work, I don't understand why because it should not.

Comment: If you're constructing a list *of lists*, then a list *is* "one item". If that makes sense...

Comment: Note you can use `1:2:[3, 4, 5]` because of right-associativity.

Comment: `[1,2]:[1,2]:[]` should work fine in ghci.

Answer (score 5):

Well, let's review some things.  the **principal** (= most general) type of the `:` operator is this:

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

`a` is a type variable.  What this whole thing means is that every time the operator is actually used, the context of its usage determines what type `a` will stand for in that particular use.  So if you're doing this:

```
example1 :: [Integer]
example1 = 5 : [1, 2]
```

...in that context `a` is `Integer`, and if you're doing this:

```
example2 :: [[Integer]]
example2 = [1,2] : [[1,2]]
```

...then in that context `a` is `[Integer]`.  So what the type means:

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

...is that the type `a` of the value you're putting at the head of the list must be the same as the type of the values that go into that list.  If it's a list whose elements are `Integer`s then the value must be an `Integer` as well.  And in the example that's confusing you, we have a *list of lists of `Integer`s*, so the first argument of `:` in that context is a list of `Integer`.

Haskell is very precise about this, so we could keep going with other examples illustrating the same principle.  Here for example we put a list of lists in front of a list of lists of lists:

```
example3 :: [[[Integer]]]
example3 = [[1, 2], [3, 4]] : [[[1, 2]]]
-- Value: [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2]]]
```

So going again to the principal type of `:`:

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Another way of looking at it is as a *pattern* that all of the uses of `:` must obey: the type of the first argument must have one pair of square brackets fewer than the types of the second argument and the result.  Another thing it tells us is that `:` doesn't care about what type `a` may be—it could be a simple value like `Integer`, or it could be some complex thing like `[[[[Integer]]]]`, and this function just can't tell the difference.

Answer (score 4):

> My Question: How does this work? I don't understand why because it should not.

You're wrong in that it should not, and you're wrong because you forgot that `a` might as well mean `[a]`.

Let's look at some type equations:

```
[]          :: [a]
(:)         :: a -> [a] -> [a]
[1,2,3]     :: [Int]
0 : [1,2,3] :: [Int]
```

Now with a twist:

```
[]                 :: [[a]]
(:)                :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
[[1,2], [3]]       :: [[Int]]
[0] : [[1,2], [3]] :: [[Int]]
```

A list of lists is **still a list**, of which an element appended by `:` is... a list.

Comment: Alright, a bit clearer now, but still. in a function replicate2 i don't define anywhere im building a list of lists. if try something like 5:6 in a CHCI it dosen't automaticaly build a list [5,6] it throws an error. same if i try [1,2]:[3,4] it dosent automaticaly bulild [[1,2],[3,4]]. However in this function im essentially doing this: [1,2]:[1,2]:[] and it returns [[1,2],[1,2]]. Do you undestand what i mean? if you look at replicate2 function it is adding a list to a list   but  not  a list to a list of lists. How does this magic happen?

Comment: oh no.. wait, if i check functions type definition with :t it says:
replicate2 :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> a -> [a] . so its defined to return a list and since im adding lists to THAT list it returns a list of lists? i think i got it.

Comment: @EasternDude You say: "if I try [1,2]:[3,4] it doesn't work, but this function is essentially doing [1,2]:[1,2]:[]". Well, that extra `:[]` at the end makes all the difference! With `[1,2]:[3,4]`, you are trying to add the element `[1,2]` to the list with elements `3` and `4`, and `[1,2]` and `3` have different types. But with `[1,2]:[1,2]:[]`, you are first adding the element `[1,2]` to the list with no elements (hence no type mismatch yet), then adding the element `[1,2]` to the list with one element, `[1,2]`. Those have the same type, so there's no type mismatch.